# How to remove charset=utf-8 in a Content-Type header, generated by grails

Tags: grails

I'm trying to send json data as a response body in grails. I've tried setting the Content-Type header to application/json using the following methods:

```
render (status: httpServletResponse, text: responseToRender as JSON, contentType: "application/json")
```

Each time the resulting header is as follows:

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

How do I get rid of the charset=UTF-8 postfix?

Answer (score 1):

You can not get rid of the charset postfix.
You can change it with the charset parameter defined here:

https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html

You can also provide no information by just handing json to render, such as:

```
response.setContentType("application/json")
render JsonOutput.toJson(responseToRender);
```

However, this will default to the standard encoding required by HTTP 1.1 which is ISO-8859-1. therefore your result would be application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1

https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index.en

So, if you somehow need to use this parameter, you may use .split(";")[0] to access only the first part.

Answer (score 0):

You can render a JSON String with

```
response.setContentType("application/json")
response.outputStream << jsonVar
```

Then your header will be only

```
Content-Type:application/json
```