# How to remove charset=utf8 from Content-Type?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I need to remove  `charset=utf-8`, from Content-Type. I have to use fetch, and for now I'm sending this:

```
fetch(`address/${endpoint}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(testData)
    });
```

this is how it looks like:
[image: 1]

I have to remove a charset.
If I didn't clarify it enough, please tell me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Fetch: characters with encoding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282444/javascript-fetch-characters-with-encoding-issues)

Comment: The server is misbehaving when you include `charset=...` in the request…?

Comment: Yes, it threw an error 415.

Comment: Check this link out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180536/how-to-remove-charset-utf-8-in-a-content-type-header-generated-by-grails

Comment: Is the `charset=utf-8` part added to the request headers ? Or is your problem with the response headers ?

Comment: It's not added by myself, I guess it's there by default.